# Need to populate two textboxes in adobe acrobat based on selection from combobox

Tags: javascript, pdf, combobox, adobe, acrobat

Comboboxes in Acrobat do not allow text alignment or multiple lines. So I need to be able to select from a drop down box and my choice populate two textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

A "drop down box" *is* a combo box. Case you're actually referring to a *list box*:

Get the selected indices using:

```
var a = this.getField("listbox").currentValueIndices;
```

Retrieve the value of an index by calling:

```
this.getField("listbox").getItemAt(index, false);
```

Set the value of a textfield:

```
this.getField("textField").value = "new value".
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I think you got me on the right track.

this.getField("textField").value = this.getField("combobox").value;

that's what I came up with, but it only seems to work once.

Comment: Make sure you add the script to the right event. I think the safest would be to run the code under Calculate->Custom calculation script.